# Static files not available in developer mode

Tags: magento2.2, developer-mode

I'm running Magento 2.2.2 in developer mode.
When I try to display a page, the static files are not available unless I remove all the pub folder content with `rm -R pub/static/*`
Once it's done, the static files are available only one time. If I refresh the page, they're gone :

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js”.
```

(same error for several other js and css files)

I tried `setup:static-content:deploy` but it doesn't fix the issue.
After working on it for several hours, my guess is that something is wrong with the symlink but I don't get where, when I use `readlink` the path is correct : `lib/web/requirejs/require.js`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: issue might because of permission of static directory, so please set permission first

Comment: I have checked all the permissions following this : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Answer (score 1):

When You remove **pub/static/*** folder, You removed **.htaccess** file.

Keep in mind never delete **pub/static/.htaccess**

You can download .htaccess file from the [official Magento 2 repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2). That will solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, ´rm -R pub/static/*´ doesn't remove the .htaccess (which is hidden), read here : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/clean_static_cache.html
However, I tried to replace the .htaccess with the one from the M2 repository, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please check front folder static folder after deploy content

Comment: Checked : same problem with the frontend files.

Answer (score 0):

first remove all files or folders inside :
1)pub/static (except .htaccess file inside static folder)
2) var/cache

than run commands in following order :

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cron:run
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and if you will still face error , set permissions  :
Permission commands:

```
---------------------------------------
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;                        // 644 permission for files
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;                        // 755 permission for directory  
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;                // 777 permission for var folder     
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
-----------------------------------------------
```

also find "Symlink" keyword in app/etc/di.xml , remove it with Copy.

Comment: I have run all the commands you advised with no result.
I have found and deleted `<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>` in app/etc/di.xml with no result either.
Any other idea ? Thanks.